# Erasing duplicates from two vectors using only iterators

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, vector, iterator

How can I delete duplicates from two vectors of strings (delete them from both vectors) using only iterators?

I suppose it doesn't work because if values are already deleted they can't be compared, but I can not think of any other solution, only if I had one function to erase both elements at the same time.

```cpp
void obrisiIsteRijeci(std::vector<std::string>& v1, std::vector<std::string>& v2){
    for(auto it = v1.begin(); it != v1.end(); it++){
        auto it1 = it;
        for(auto it2 = v2.begin(); it2 != v2.end(); it2++){
            if((*(it2) == *(it1)) && (*(it1) == *(it2))){
                v1.erase(it1);
                v2.erase(it2);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what if one vector is `[1 1 1]` and the other is `[2 2 2]`, then both should remain unchanged?

Comment: Are the vectors sorted?  If so, so you can use `set_intersection` to find the common elements between then vectors, and then you can remove those values from each vector.

Comment: `v2.erase(it2)`  And on the next iteration of the loop, `it2++` is invalid, because you erased it.

Comment: *using only iterators* -- What exactly does this mean?  Just stating this is basically meaningless.  So if another container is created, and iterators are used there, does that count?

Comment: Wow, so many parentheses in that `if` condition. I'm lost.

Comment: @PeteBecker: There are a few useless parens there.  As well as distrust that the `==` operator on `std::string` is commutative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can suggest the following approach. In the demonstration program below I am using vectors of the type `std::vector<int>` for simplicity.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
$include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 4 }, v2 = { 1, 2, 3, 5 };

    for (auto first = std::begin( v1 ); first != std::end( v1 ); )
    {
        auto it = std::find( std::begin( v2 ), std::end( v2 ), *first );

        if (it != std::end( v2 ))
        {
            v2.erase( std::remove( it, std::end( v2 ), *first ), std::end( v2 ) );

            auto value = *first;
            auto offset = std::distance( std::begin( v1 ), first );

            v1.erase( std::remove( first, std::end( v1 ), value ), std::end( v1 ) );
            first = std::next( std::begin( v1 ), offset );
        }
        else
        {
            ++first;
        }
    }

    for (const auto &item : v1)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    for (const auto &item : v2)
    {
        std::cout << item << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

The program output is

```
4
5
```

Comment: This is converting from iterators to indexes and back to iterators again.  I would think that the "using only iterators" restriction in the question is meant to prohibit use of indexes.

Comment: @BenVoigt Where are you seeing indices? All operations with iterators.

Comment: The variable `offset` is an index, `std::distance` transforms an iterator to an index, and `std::next` transforms an index to an iterator

Comment: @BenVoigt With the same success you could say that an expression like ++it (by the way it is used in the function next for non random access iterators)  transforms iterators in indices.:) Moreover a call like this std::next( it ) is equivalent to the call std::next( it, 1 );

Comment: It's not the increment in `std::next` that is related to indexes, it's the number-of-steps argument.  Particularly when, as this answer does, that number is measured from `std::begin(v1)`.

Comment: @BenVoigt It can be equivalently done using a previous iterator instead of using distance and next..

Comment: Yes, that would conform to the restriction.

Comment: @BenVoigt I am sure she meant the subscript operator or loops with an index,